# How to show toString() at IntelliJ debug of kotlin.time.Duration

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug my Kotlin code in IntelliJ IDEA. When I use a kotlin.time.Duration object and print it using println, I get the expected output in the console ("1h"). However, when I check the variable in the debugger, it shows a long value (7200000000000).

Here's an example:

```
val test: Duration = 1.hours
println(test) //Consol out = "1h"
```

Debugger shows:

```
test: long = 7200000000000
```

Is there a way to make the debugger display the toString() representation of the Duration object, similar to what println shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug - [IDEA-335220](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-335220/Incorrect-toString-representation-of-unboxed-inline-value-classes-in-debug-window). A [similar bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-337026/Evaluating-an-instance-of-a-value-class-produces-an-unboxed-result) is "In Progress", so this will probably be fixed in the near future.

This happens because [`Duration`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/#duration) is a [value class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) that wraps a `Long`. The debugger shows the inlined `Long`, instead of using the value class's `toString` implementation.